# Nextjs onclick data to div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using a table to display data. I would like to get the row data into a div when the user clicks the table row:

**Currently I am getting the data onclick which is working:**

```
const handleClick = (rowData) =>  {
    console.log(rowData);
}
```

**Although currently not sure how I should pass and change the data into the div, here's the full code:**

```
const Start = ({rowData}) => {
  const options = {
    onRowClick: rowData => handleClick(rowData),
  }; // MUI Datatables onRowClick, works fine

  const handleClick = (rowData) =>  {
      console.log(rowData); // shows data in console, works
  }
  return (
          <div className="tablehead">
              <h2>({rowData})</h2> // no data here, how to pass the onclick data here?
          </div>
  )
}
export default Start;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's happened here is that you have mixed up passing row data props with a variable that is the same name. Instead you need to look into managing state through hooks.

```
const Start = ({rowData}) => {
  const [dataForDisplay, setDataForDisplay] = useState(rowData);

  const handleClick = (rowData) =>  {
      setDataForDisplay(rowData);
  }
  return (
          <div className="tablehead">
              <h2>({dataForDisplay})</h2> 
          </div>
  )
}
export default Start;
```

However using props to seed state is most of the time an anti-pattern, so you might want to reconsider your component hierarchy. Either way however you'll need to look into state management and hooks.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html